# I need permutations between multiple lists and i need it to be done fastest and most efficient way possible

Tags: python, permutation

I have  multiple lists of numbers like these:

```
a = np.arange(100,150,1).tolist()
b = np.arange(300,330,1).tolist()
c = np.arange(600,900,1).tolist()
d = np.arange(1250,1400,1).tolist()
```

i need permutations between these lists with specific length (**my ultimate goal is to choose the one permutation that satisfy my conditions such as distance between each number in permutation**), for example if length is `3` i want : `(100,300,600)` and ... and if length is `2` i want `(100,300)` and ...
i used itertools but my computer crashed everytime , is there an efficient way to do it? or do i need some kind of algorithm to do it faster and not calculate all possible permutations ?

thank you

Comment: Could you provide more info about the expected results? It's not really clear to me

Comment: @user2246849 Does your input consist of numpy array of numbers? Do you need to convert them to lists first? You should actually show us what you tried with itertools. If it crashed you probably were storing too much into memory.

Comment: each permutation is the x coordinate of some nodes! for example (100,300) are two nodes, first has x coordinate equal to 100 and the second node  has x coordinate equal to 300,  eventually i want permutation or permutations that gives me x coordinates that are divisible by 12, for example (120,240) is acceptable but (130,250) is not.

Comment: For your example, would `(100, 301)` also be valid for length 2? What about `(100, 600)`?

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use a [process pool executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor).

If you are running out of memory, then maybe it would be better to use workers and a [queue or deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

Comment: I hope you are okay with my edits. I simply created hyperlinks. Raw links look messy.